# Do kiwi berry guild well with with elderberry?

Tags: companion-planting

I've heard a lot about planting trees together, and was wondering if Kiwiberry will guild well with John/Adams elderberry.

Comment: Latin names, plase.

Comment: not available from the catalog.

Comment: what do you mean by the term 'guild'? Also note that kiwiberry is not a tree....

Comment: guilds are putting plants together so they make each other stronger to strengthen their weaknesses.

Comment: can you cite your source for this particular meaning of guild in this horticultural context please? Or are you saying its a meaning you've created yourself? Question's irrelevant anyway - elderberry (Sambucus) is a tree, kiwiberry is a climbing vine.

Comment: Permaculture guilds are probably what he's thinking about http://www.neverendingfood.org/b-what-is-permaculture/permaculture-guilds/

Comment: @Bamboo You might call elderberries trees, because they get as tall as trees, but unlike most trees, they constantly shoot up new trunks or canes, like a currant bush does. I've always heard them called bushes.

Comment: @Bamboo I'm getting a johns and adams elderberry partners, and they will be colonizing away from each other with kiwis hanging down from them.

Comment: @Shule - that rather depends whether Black Thumb is referring to Sambucus nigra or Sambucus canadensis , because he hadn't specified - S.nigra is a small tree about 20 feet, S. canadensis is rather more shrubby and about half that height. If the question had been clearer, there'd have been no need for all these comments/questions. I wouldn't describe S. canadensis as a tree - its more or a shrub, yet 'tree' is in the question... which is likely why Stephie asked for the Latin names in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sambucus canadiensis (or S. nigra subsp. canadiensis)<sup>1</sup> is not suited as "support" or "trellis" for *anything* with significant weight, especially not for vines - and kiwiberry is thick and strong enough to support hanging bridges...

If I harvest elderflowers or berries, I use a walking stick or similar to gently pull down higher branches. Young shots are very flexible. Old wood, on the other hand, is quite brittle and breaks easily.

So no, this is absolutely no feasible plan.

---

<sup>1</sup> I presume that's what we are talking about according to our previous discussions...

Answer (score 1):

Elderberry is a large bush, and kiwi berry is a rapidly growing vine that can climb 100 feet up a tree. Physically they don't sound like a good pair. And furthermore you'll need a pair of both.

Kiwifruit is normally grown horizontally on trellises to make picking the fruit easier as it's quite labor intensive even without it climbing up a tree.

Comment: you can form it into a tree, just like cherries that you mow down after establishment become a bush.

Comment: And it's going to support a vine that grows 100 foot long, allowing the kiwi sufficient sun without collapsing under the weight?

Comment: @GrahamChiu, no idea why this was downvoted, you are spot on. Elder is a bush, not a tree.

Comment: @Stephie - Sambucus nigra is a tree - Sambucus canadensis, which seems to be what Black Thumb is talking about now he's added the Johns and Adams bit, isn't... a clear question is worth its weight in gold... and it wasn't me who downvoted, I'm about to give a point in fact

Comment: @Bamboo my sources said "shrub" for both, which makes sense for me and matches my observation, especially with the discussion whether S. canadiensis is a subspecies of S. nigra or not. And for the record, I upvoted, too. ;-)